# unable to initialise cache of squid proxy server

Tags: squid, proxy

I have just installed Squid on Centos 6.2 x86 based system.

I am trying to configure it through the Squid module for Webmin.

When I go to that screen I get the following message--

```
Your Squid cache directory /var/spool/squid has not been initialized.This must be done before Squid can be run.
```

I have tried running the following 2 commands, the commands along with their output are given below--

```
[root@server ~]# squid -z
2012/02/10 11:03:37| Creating Swap Directories
[root@server ~]#  /usr/sbin/squid -f /etc/squid/squid.conf -z
2012/02/10 11:11:24| Creating Swap Directories
```

When I go back to the squid module on webmin, I get the same message (as given below) again--

```
Your Squid cache directory /var/spool/squid has not been initialized.This must be done before Squid can be run.
```

How do I initialise squid cache correctly?

Comment: Is `/var/spool/squid` and the cache directories under it owned by the same user that squid is running as? If they're owned by root, the squid user might not be able to read them... just a thought.

Comment: @AndySmith - yes they are owned by the user 'squid' which is the user that squid is running as...

Answer (score 3):

Try including this directive in your `squid.conf` file from backend and restart the squid.

```
cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 1000 16 256
```